# Salesforce Console for Service vs. Salesforce Console for Sales

Tags: service-cloud-console, console, sales-cloud

When accessing/using Console, what is the difference between:

A. Giving a user Service Cloud User (which you can provide using the check box in their profile);

B. Sales Console User permission set license?

Does one give more/less access than the other?

My org. uses Sales Cloud so we are able to set up Console but I am not sure which of the above to use when I need to provide users access to the Console itself. I tested it out (in terms of access) and anyone with either or of the above is able to access the Console so that is my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Either of those perms will give the user access to Salesforce Console apps. Service Cloud includes additional permissions such as Entitlements & Milestones.